# Errors in an if statement

Tags: if-statement

I try running this code but the problem is -since I'm a beginner -  I don't know how to place several conditions in one if statement and why the if line and else linke have errors. Can you please show me where I went wrong ? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

double AVG;
cout<< "please write in average\n";
cin>> AVG;
if ((AVG >60) && (AVG >=90))----------expected identifier
    cout<< "pass with grade of " << AVG ;
    cout << "\n" << "A star!\n";
else----------------------------------expected expression
    cout << "fail with grade of " << AVG << "\n";
cout<< "good luck with your smester !\n";

}
```

Comment: Side note: I think you want to add curly braces below the `if`.

Comment: Side note #2: The condition `(AVG >60) && (AVG >=90)` is a kinda ridiculous.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please show me how ?

Comment: Side note #3: Function `main` should return a value (typically `return 0;` is "good enough").

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you and there is no need to add `(AVG >60) && (AVG >=90)` both as if `AVG>=90` then `AVG >60` is true already.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    double AVG;
    cout<< "please write in average\n";
    cin>> AVG;
    if (AVG >=90)
    {
        cout<< "pass with grade of " << AVG ;
        cout << "\n" << "A star!\n";
    }
    else
    {  
        cout << "fail with grade of " << AVG << "\n";
        cout<< "good luck with your smester !\n";
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't provide an explanation to the `expected identifier` compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using more than one statement please use parenthesis and you are using int main() then you need to return a value.

**Updated Code**

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){

    double AVG;
    cout<< "please write in average\n";
    cin>> AVG;
   if ((AVG >60) && (AVG >=90))
   {
     cout<< "pass with grade of " << AVG ;
     cout << "\n" << "A star!\n";
   }
 else{
    cout << "fail with grade of " << AVG << "\n";
     cout<< "good luck with your smester !\n";
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This answer doesn't provide an explanation to the `expected identifier` compilation error.